# Using API in Bash without curl

Tags: bash, api

I'm writing a script that has a function using a weather API. for now I only managed to solve this problem with `curl` but I recently noticed I don have access to `curl` where I need the script to run. Is there any other way I can solve this? The code I have is this:

```
weatherLondon()
{
    echo "<h3>Weather in London</h3>"
    (( $# )) || set -- "London,UK"
    echo "Location: ${1//,/, }"
    curl -s "http://api.wunderground.com/auto/wui/geo/ForecastXML/index.xml?query=$1" | perl -ne 's/&amp;deg;/°/g;
                                                                                                s/ \(\d+°F\)//g;
                                                                                                /<title>([^<]+)/ && printf "%s: ",$1;
                                                                                                /<fcttext>([^<]+)/ && print $1,"\n"';
}
```

I found this code at http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/4821/get-the-weather-forecast-for-the-next-24-to-48-for-your-location

I'm very new with both bash and API's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use good old `wget`. It should be part of almost every Linux distribution (unless not administratively removed). Replace your curl statement with:

```
wget -q -O - "http://api.wunderground.com/auto/wui/geo/ForecastXML/index.xml?query=$1"
```

`-O -` sets the output to standard output, `-q` suppresses debugging output like curl's `-s`

Comment: It worked great! Anyway you know how to make this work for The guardians API as well? http://www.theguardian.com/open-platform/getting-started

Comment: The script for the weather is working perfectly, I would just like to have another one for a news from taken from an API, for example The Guardian.

Comment: Presenting a fully fledged API integration is too much for this format. Mostly API vendors will support some programming language client libraries, or there are open source client libraries. I would search for this..